# Calendar Issue, overlays issue on events in SharePoint 2013

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-calendar

When the Calendar loads first time, The event overlays appears on the top of the Calendar as shown in the figure 1) .

[image]

But when we refresh the page, the overlay event goes back to its original place as shown in the Figure 2).

[image]

This behavior is only noticed when there is a custom master page applied to the site. It seems to be no way to adjust this. Have anyone encounter such issue?

I have created a `Custom Master Page` using Visual Studio.

**Edit:** I am making few ajax async calls in the master Page. When i commented the ajax calls in the master page the overlays display properly.
Click [Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/175590/applying-oob-theme-to-sharepoint-2013-custom-master-page-created-in-visual-studi) is the code in my master Page.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome (Developer Tools) to debug it. Could be a javascript file is not loaded probably, but hard to tell without debugging.

Comment: Please see my edit to the question, as to why the issue is appearing.